# Floating Labels input not registering text

Tags: javascript, css, label, floating

This is a weird one.  Earlier today, I posted code for a form that had floating labels.  The problem was that the JS within the code that would register if the cursor or text had been put into the input was not working because, regardless of what you put in there, the label would float back down.

When I posted the code a few people said it was working fine on their end and even copied the code back into jsfiddle and THEIR VERSION WORKED.  I took their version of the code that worked and copied it into a blank js fiddle to compare the code, and it promptly stopped working again.

Can anyone please help me.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".formStyle7 .input-group input").focusout(function() {

    var text_val = $(this).val();
    if (text_val === "") {
      $(this).removeClass('has-value');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('has-value');
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.formStyle7 {
  display: block;
  height: 750px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: rgb(128, 128, 128) .1px .1px 5px, rgb(128, 128, 128) -.1px -.1px 5px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
input {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #21a1e1;
  margin: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 455px;
}
input:focus,
input:active {
  outline: none;
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b3c1cc;
}
.input-group {
  position: relative;
}
.input-group label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 30px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #999;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.input-group input:focus + label,
.input-group input.has-value + label {
  top: 13px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #aaa;
}
#proposedWorkshopDDL {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #21a1e1;
  margin: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 455px;
}
#unitPresidentDDL {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #21a1e1;
  margin: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 455px;
}
.clearFix {
  clear: both;
}
header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 500px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida         Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #b3c1cc;
  float: left;
  margin: 25px 10px 0px 15px;
}
p {
  height: 40px;
  width: 500px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #b3c1cc;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.formContainer {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="formStyle7">

  <header>OECTA PD Network Workshop</header>
  <p>Workshop Application Form</p>
  <div class="clearFix"></div>

  <div class="formContainer">

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" />
      <label>First Name</label>
    </div>


    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" />
      <label>Last Name</label>
    </div>


    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="email" />
      <label>Email Address</label>
    </div>


    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" />
      <label>Contact Number</label>
    </div>


    <select id="unitPresidentDDL">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Unit 1</option>
      <option>Unit 2</option>
      <option>Unit 3</option>
    </select>


    <select id="proposedWorkshopDDL">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Workshop 1</option>
      <option>Workshop 2</option>
      <option>Workshop 3</option>
    </select>

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" />
      <label>Date for Workshop</label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" />
      <label>Time for Workshop</label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" />
      <label>Location for Workshop</label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="submit" />
    </div>


  </div>
```

Comment: Just changed your code to run and seems fine to me in the latest chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested your code, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/jb013rqe/3/

But it looks like you forgot to include jQuery as an external dependency:

[image]

Just add an jquery cdn url to the External Resources section, e.g.:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: Oh my gosh that's it!

Comment: Man, I've been pulling my hair out all morning!  Remember the Michigan Frog?  That's what it felt like

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure you have jquery loaded on the page.

It seems to work fine for me. The placeholder in the input shrinks up and stays there if text is in the input. Try putting your js in this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   /*Code here*/
});
```

If that does not work are there any console errors?